# C# Can't find reference system.web.ui

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, .net-2.0

I'm using framework 2.0 and trying to build  project,but i'm getting a lot of errors in the aspx.designer.cs pages,example.

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel updMenu;
```

The error says the name UpdatePanel doesn't exist in the web.ui namespace,i think its because the framework doesn't support this?Or it't other thing that is causing this?

In the references i have the system.web,i exlucluded and included multiple times and errors continues.

[image]

Comment: Is this asp.net-mvc ????

Comment: Yes,its a asp.net application

Comment: This is not Asp.NET MVC, it's Asp.NET WebForms

Comment: And if you're trying to use UpdatePanel, that requires .NET 3.5 - as per the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx (Why are you using .NET 2.0 anyway?)

Comment: Thanks Jon,its the framework indeed

Comment: Jon is a Pantomath :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use .Net Framework 3.5 or upper.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx